# What im doing wrong? [MATLAB - function fill]

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, fill, area

How can I fill the area below the curve `batha`?

I tried creating two polygons and using the fill function, but none of my approaches worked. This was my best result obtained:

```matlab
batha = [7.1333, 7.2417, 8.9061, 11.3646, 12.4889, 13.4572, 14.2250, 14.9386, 15.6905, 16.3310, 16.9292, 17.5558, 18.1131, 18.6633, 19.1629, 19.6635, 20.1515, 20.5933  21.0977, 21.5496, 21.9330, 22.2395, 22.5265, 22.7585, 23.1206, 23.4995, 23.9305, 24.2578, 24.6371, 25.1523, 25.4367, 25.6555, 25.9033, 26.1234, 26.2947, 26.4327, 26.5938, 26.6785, 26.7185, 26.7620, 26.8082, 26.7954, 26.7736, 26.7620, 26.7115, 26.5621, 26.3871, 26.1397, 25.9179, 25.6900, 25.4573, 25.1153, 24.7805, 24.4380, 24.0568, 23.7017, 23.3502, 22.9135, 22.5052, 22.0068, 21.4806, 21.0029, 20.5206, 20.0435, 19.5195, 18.9530, 18.4100, 17.9349, 17.4666, 17.0207, 16.5991, 16.1766, 15.8215, 15.6079, 15.4509, 15.2146, 14.9472, 14.7120, 14.3792, 14.0351, 13.7436, 13.4690, 13.1548, 12.9656, 12.8458, 12.6870, 12.5101, 12.2376, 11.8062, 11.3752, 10.9464, 10.4963, 10.0391, 9.5816, 9.1367, 8.7270, 8.2709, 7.7497, 7.0903, 6.1263];
bdii = [0, 0.0303, 0.0606, 0.0909, 0.1212, 0.1515, 0.1818, 0.2121, 0.2424, 0.2727, 0.3030, 0.3333, 0.3636, 0.3939, 0.4242, 0.4545, 0.4848, 0.5152, 0.5455, 0.5758, 0.6061, 0.6364, 0.6667, 0.6970, 0.7273, 0.7576, 0.7879, 0.8182, 0.8485, 0.8788, 0.9091, 0.9394, 0.9697, 1.0000, 1.0303, 1.0606, 1.0909, 1.1212, 1.1515, 1.1818, 1.2121, 1.2424, 1.2727, 1.3030, 1.3333, 1.3636, 1.3939, 1.4242, 1.4545, 1.4848, 1.5152, 1.5455, 1.5758, 1.6061, 1.6364, 1.6667, 1.6970, 1.7273, 1.7576, 1.7879, 1.8182, 1.8485, 1.8788, 1.9091, 1.9394, 1.9697, 2.0000, 2.0303, 2.0606, 2.0909, 2.1212, 2.1515, 2.1818, 2.2121, 2.2424, 2.2727, 2.3030, 2.3333, 2.3636, 2.3939, 2.4242, 2.4545, 2.4848, 2.5152, 2.5455, 2.5758, 2.6061, 2.6364, 2.6667, 2.6970, 2.7273, 2.7576, 2.7879, 2.8182, 2.8485, 2.8788, 2.9091, 2.9394, 2.9697, 3.0000];

%Adjusting the bathymetry

batha=-1.*batha;


plot(bdii,batha(1,:),'k'); hold on;

x0 = min(bdii);
y0 = max(batha);
x1 = max(bdii);
y1 = min(batha);

fill([x0, bdii],[y0, batha],'g');
fill([x1, bdii],[y1, batha],'y');
```

[image: pic png]

I tried the `fill` and `area` functions.

Comment: Which area do you want to fill? Why is your result not good enough? It is always better to give too many details than too few, remember we don’t know what you now, only what you write down in the post.

Comment: Can u open the "pic png"? There are two areas, one green and the other yellow bugged. My goal is to fill the yellow (below) area...

Comment: I see two yellow areas. This is because you added a point`(x1,y1)` to the polygon you fill with yellow, causing the polygon to be self-intersecting. What is  your expected output? Do you want to fill the area below the function `batha` in yellow?

Comment: Exactly Chris!
And thanks for editing the post, I'm still learning

Comment: OK. You need to add a point `(x0,y1)` at the start of the polygon, and `(x1,y1)` at the end. This will add the two vertices at the left and right side, and when closing  the polygon it will automatically insert the vertex along the bottom. Maybe you want to make `y1` a little lower, depending on what your aesthetic goals are. :)